# Sum of attribute values by another attribute

Tags: xslt-1.0

I've the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers>
  <ContainerGroup Type="40HC" Quantity="1"/> 
  <ContainerGroup Type="40HC" Quantity="3"/> 
  <ContainerGroup Type="42PL" Quantity="4"/> 
  <ContainerGroup Type="40HC" Quantity="2"/> 
</Containers>
```

Need to write an xsl 1.0 code so that the result is

```
<Sum>40HC-6||42PL-4</Sum>
```

Tried using below code but didn't worked

```
<xsl:for-each select="Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type">
  <xsl:variable name="sumQuantity" select="sum(@Quantity)" />
  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">||</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Type,'-',$sumQuantity)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**EDIT 1**
using Muenchian method, developed below code but its not working

```
  <xsl:key name="container-by-type" match="Containers/ContainerGroup" use="Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type"/>
  <xsl:template name="sumQuantity">     
    <xsl:for-each select="//Containers/ContainerGroup[generate-id() = generate-id(key('container-by-type', Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type)[1])]">
      <xsl:variable name="grp" select="key('container-by-type', Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type)" />
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">||</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type,'-',sum($grp/@Quantity))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) problem. Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. There are many examples that you can find here.

Comment: P.S. Some XSLT 1.0 processors support extension functions that can make the process easier, for example EXSLT `set:distinct()`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k using the Muenchian method, I've developed below code, but somehow it is not working. Can you help me where is the issue?

Comment: <xsl:key name="container-by-type" match="Containers/ContainerGroup" use="Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type"/>
 <xsl:template name="sumQuantity">  
  <xsl:for-each select="//Containers/ContainerGroup[generate-id() = generate-id(key('container-by-type', Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type)[1])]">
   <xsl:variable name="grp" select="key('container-by-type', Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type)" />
   <xsl:if test="position() != 1">||</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(Containers/ContainerGroup/@Type,'-',sum($grp/@Quantity))"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Code is added under EDIT 1 section

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k, your code worked! The only change i did is to add // before ContainerGroup in the generate id statement. Anyway, Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes, most notably using an absolute path where a relative path is required. We also don't see where you named template is being called and from what context.

Compare to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="container-by-type" match="ContainerGroup" use="@Type"/>

<xsl:template match="/Containers">
    <Sum>
        <!-- create a group for each distinct type -->
        <xsl:for-each select="ContainerGroup[generate-id()=generate-id(key('container-by-type', @Type)[1])]">
            <!-- output the type -->
            <xsl:value-of select="@Type" />
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <!-- sum the curent group's quantities -->
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('container-by-type', @Type)/@Quantity)" />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">||</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Sum>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```